# Python program to find the two oldest from the inputs(without lists)

Tags: python, while-loop

I was given this exercise where the program has to get inputs(the inputs are people's ages) until "-1" is entered .After "-1 "is entered the program has to print the two biggest numbers(two oldest people's age). But I'm not allowed to use lists.
I came up with the program below, but the thing is that when I only enter the number 10 11 and then -1 the program outputs 11 as the biggest number (oldest), and 0 as the second biggest number (second oldest), whereas it should have printed 11 as the biggest number and 10 as the second biggest number.
What do you think is wrong with my code?

```
oldest_age=0
second_oldest_age=0
age=int(input())
while age!=-1:
    age=int(input())
    if age>oldest_age:
        second_oldest_age=oldest_age
        oldest_age=age
    elif age<oldest_age and age>second_oldest_age:
        second_oldest_age=age
else:
    print(oldest_age, second_oldest_age)
```

Comment: You have `age=int(input())` before the loop and that value is never used. You can change to `oldest_age = second_oldest_age = age = int(input())` to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the input to the end of the loop. If you don't do that, the first input is not used (apart from in the while loop condition), as it is immediately over-written by the next input.

```py
oldest_age = 0
second_oldest_age = 0
age = int(input())
while age != -1:
    if age > oldest_age:
        second_oldest_age = oldest_age
        oldest_age = age
    elif age > second_oldest_age: # 'age < oldest_age' is not needed here
        second_oldest_age = age
    age = int(input()) # Moved this from the start to the end
else:
    print(oldest_age, second_oldest_age)
```

Comment: Thank you, it finally workeddd

Comment: Sorry but as English is not my mother tongue I don't get the last part of your comments meaning :)

Comment: @Annahita - that's ok. If you click the check mark (✓) next to my answer, it will accept.